# Elasticsearch 6 create new field requires data type but "Indices created in 6.x only allow a single-type per index"

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

Create a new field in Elasticsearch 6.6.2 gives the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
            "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;"
         }
      ],
      "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
      "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;"
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

The request:

```
curl --request PUT http://10.1.3.81:9200/netswitch_message/_mapping -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \
'{
   "properties": {
     "amount": {"type": "integer"}
   }
 }'
```

gives error no matter what data type I use. The index already has types integer, text/keyword, text and date.

```sh
curl --request PUT http://10.1.3.81:9200/netswitch_message/_mapping -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"properties\": {\"amount\": {\"type\": \"integer\"}}}"
curl --request PUT http://10.1.3.81:9200/netswitch_message/_mapping -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"properties\": {\"amount\": {\"type\": \"text\"}}}"
curl --request PUT http://10.1.3.81:9200/netswitch_message/_mapping/data -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"properties\": {\"amount\": {}}}"
curl --request PUT http://10.1.3.81:9200/netswitch_message/_mapping -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"properties\": {\"amount\": {}}}

Expected to create a new field
Actually got syntax error:
    {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;"}],"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;"},"status":400}
```

Comment: Can you add the existing mapping of index?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that 6.x restricts you to a single `_type`, but you do still need to supply the name of that type (in 7.x, it defaults to `_doc`).

Change your mapping to specify the `_type`, like the following which sets it to "my-type":

```
curl --request PUT http://10.1.3.81:9200/netswitch_message/_mapping/my-type -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \
'{
    "properties": {
       "amount": {"type": "integer"}
    }
 }'
```

See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/indices-put-mapping.html#indices-put-mapping